# Solving an equation that contains a variable which brings 0=0 issue

Tags: derivatives, chain-rule

So I encountered this question:

Given that the relationship between distance (m) and velocity (v) of an object is $$v^2 = 1 - m^3$$

Find the acceleration of the object when $m=1$

By taking the derivative of each side with respect to $t$

$2v \frac{dv}{dt} = -3m^2 \frac{dm}{dt} $

and we know that $\frac{dv}{dt}$ = acceleration, $\frac{dm}{dt}$ is equal to $v$, then:

$2v  a = -3m^2 v$

and by solving for $a$ without dividing by $v$ since $v$ can be zero, $a = -3/2$

But hold on... we've just substituted $m$ with 1, this means that we have to substitute $v$ with zero, but if we do this we would turn out with 0 = 0, without solving for $a$

That's how our teacher solved it. My questions are: is it permissible to substitute the value for a variable and keep the other, even if i know its value?

And why did we treat $v$ here as any other number other than zero?

Comment: The answer is : no.

Comment: Cool, but if i substitute for v, i would get a 0=0 case.. What should i do?

Comment: I meant that this is wrong.

Comment: The whole question is wrong?

Comment: Substituting is wrong.

Comment: Why is it wrong? I want to find acceleration at that distance, why can't i substitute for v too?

Comment: $1-m^3$ is a difference of cubes. It can be written in the form  $(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$